# Как получить имя объекта / экземпляра объекта JavaScript

Tags: json, javascript

Ситуация такая. Паршу JSON:

```
"rates": {
    "ИМЯ": 9.049538,
    "ИМЯ": 5232.196666,
    "ИМЯ": 5.3593,
    "ИМЯ": 322.387247
}
```

Мне необходимо получить и имя и значение, если со значением выходит всё просто (data.rates.ИМЯ), то с именем выходит проблемка. Возможно ли это?

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: у вас JSON не правильный, одинаковые ключи, распарсится в 

    Object {rates: Object}
            rates: Object
                  ИМЯ: 322.387247

Comment: Это кусок JSON'а, он не полный. Просто не видел смысла сливать остальные данные, они только портят картину.

Comment: **совет** - когда приводите пример, всегда следите за тем чтобы не было конфликтующих данных - одинаковых ключей и подобного, кусок структуры хорошо - так сделайте ее валидной.

Comment: Мне кажется, что это не важно. А ваши советы - обычные придирки. Вот только не пойму - к чему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var obj = { 0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c"};
alert(Object.keys(obj)); // will alert "0,1,2"
```

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Хотя я не понял, что значит "паршу JSON".

Comment: Спасибо! А "паршу" от слова "парсить" :) Извиняюсь, не знал как по другому выразиться.

Comment: Слово-то я понял. Дело немного не в этом. Парсинг - это анализ структуры, а в случае с JSON ничего анализировать не надо, это native-представление объекта в текстовом виде.

Comment: Странно, я всегда под словом "парсить" понимал "брать откуда то данные". Но я понял, что вы имели в виду.